# celery task status showing pending

Tags: django, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I am working with celery and i am getting tasks status is pending, may be it is implementation problem. please check my code.

I am trying to save task info like id, name, status in my mongodb database, for this i am using a function which my task will call to save data in mongodb.

**Am i getting my task pending because my function call is happening before return statement of task?**

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/jobs'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 27017,
"database": "jobs",
"taskmeta_collection": "my_taskmeta_collection",
}
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-minute-contrab': {
        'task': 'username_length_periodically',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
        #'args' : (2,3),
    },
 }

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os, logging
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'RestUserAPI.settings')

app = Celery('UserAPI')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import task, current_task, result
from django.conf import settings
import datetime
from .models import TaskMetaData


@task(name='username_length_periodically', bind=True)
def get_username_length_periodically(self):
    last_run = datetime.datetime.now()
    dict = {'name':self.name,
            'id':self.request.id,
            'status':self.AsyncResult(self.request.id).state,
            'last_run': last_run,
            }
    store_metadata(dict)
    return dict


def store_metadata(dict):
    metadata = TaskMetaData()
    metadata.task_id = dict['id']
    metadata.task_name = dict['name']
    metadata.task_status = dict['status']
    metadata.task_last_run = dict['last_run']

    metadata.save()
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling this task?

Comment: i am running mongodb in one cmd, celery worker  and celery beat in another cmd.

Comment: for celery `celery -A ProjectName worker -l info` and for beat `celery -A ProjectName beat -l info`

Comment: Vikas, that's how you're running celery.  We need to see how you are kicking off your task.  Essentially, you should have something that does `get_username_length_periodically.delay` or `get_username_length_periodically.apply_async`

Comment: celery beat is doing that thing for me, It executes task after every 30sec.

Comment: look at my `settings.py` `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a plain old logic error.  If you take a look at your call to check the status of the task using `AsyncResult`:

```
'status':self.AsyncResult(self.request.id).state,
```

You'll notice that you are checking the status of the task, while the task is running.  That means that the task will always show state PENDING (unless you have track_task_started set) when you check the task because **you are always checking the status of the task from inside the task** and then never go back and update the status!

In order to update the status of the task, you should kick off a separate monitoring task that periodically checks the status of the task and records it to the database until the tasks is finished or errors out.  e.g.,

```
@app.task(name='monitor')
def monitor(task_id):
    result = AsyncResult(task_id)
    if result.state in celery.results.READY_STATES:
        # update metadata table for the task_id
        ...
    else:
        monitor.apply_async(kwargs={ 'task_id': task_id }, countdown=60)
```

Comment: thanks i got the point, but problem is how to schedule "monitor" and how i can pass task_id as a parameter to "monitor".

Comment: I am calling `monitor.apply_async(self.request.id, self.name)` inside every task and now it's working fine. Thanks @2ps.